# Replace pattern between two characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

```
Staphylococcus_sp_HMSC14C01-KV792037.1:0.00371647154267842634,Staphylococcus_hominis_VCU122-AHLD01000058.1:0.00124439639436691308)69:0.00227646100249620856,(Staphylococcus_sp_HMSC072E01-KV814990.1:0.00288325234399461859,(((Staphylococcus_hominis_793_SHAE-JUSR01000051.1:0.00594391769091206796,Staphylococcus_pettenkoferi_1286_SHAE-JVVL01000037.1:0.00594050248317441135)
```

The comma is separating different items and in each item I want to remove everything between `-` and `:` including `-` but keeping `:`.

How can I do that? So it should look like:

```
Staphylococcus_sp_HMSC14C01:0.00371647154267842634,Staphylococcus_hominis_VCU122:0.00124439639436691308)69:0.00227646100249620856
```

I used `sed 's/-.*://' 1.file > 2.file` but ended up removing the whole file and just kept the first and last values.

Comment: It looks like your input is a single line, and `sed` operates a line at a time.  Since your regular expression allows for matching `.*`, the longest (greedy) match is from the first `-` to the last `:`.  That's why it's deleting everything.  You could try replacing the `.*` with `[^,]*`, which will force it to stop at the comma between items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy regexp, matching the *longest* possible match. You need to match the shortest match but match it globally on the whole line. Try

`sed 's/-[^:-]*:/:/g' 1.file > 2.file`

The character class `[^:-]` matches anything *except* colon and dash (and maybe it should match anything except colon only), so the regexp says "dash followed by any number of non-dash, non-colon characters followed by a colon". It then replaces that with a colon (since you wanted to keep that) and does the replacement globally (the trailing `g`) on the line. If you omit the `g`, only the first instance would be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I still do not understand why cannot we say directly 
sed 's/-*:/:/g'
why do we need [^:-]?

Comment: `.*` will match the longest sequence of characters possible (that's why it's termed "greedy"). So `/-.*:/` says "dash followed by any number of characters followed by colon": that matches the first dash and the *last* colon in your line (and everything in between) because that's longer than any other match. Is that clear?

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tweaked your regex to help me convert a JSON localization file to an iOS localization file. This was so helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F',' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/-[^:-]+/,"",$i) }1' OFS=',' 1.file
```

---

- `-F','` - field separator
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all fields of the record
- `sub(/-[^:-]+/,"",$i` - substitute the needed sequence (*between **-** and **:** including **-** but keeping **:***)

---

The output:

```
Staphylococcus_sp_HMSC14C01:0.00371647154267842634,Staphylococcus_hominis_VCU122:0.00124439639436691308)69:0.00227646100249620856,(Staphylococcus_sp_HMSC072E01:0.00288325234399461859,(((Staphylococcus_hominis_793_SHAE:0.00594391769091206796,Staphylococcus_pettenkoferi_1286_SHAE:0.00594050248317441135)
```

Comment: can you explain the command?

Comment: @AhmedMagdyMoustafa, see my explanation